# Flask-strange routing issue

Tags: python, flask

So I am trying to test out serving some user uploaded files in Flask. For images I am simply renaming them with a shortened UUID and putting them in a folder, but for other file types I would like to retain the original filename, so I devised the convoluted method of saving each file in a subfolder named with a UUID. Everything works fine, both the images and files upload and are in the directories they should be in. Just to test I made a template for a download page to just display the filename(planned to implement a download button later). However, when I plug the generated URL in for an uploaded file, I get a 404, and the function that url is supposed to be bound to doesn't even appear to execute(I had it print the filename in console and it doesnt even print), and in console the url is displayed: "GET /xVgePgj2Y HTTP/1.1" 404 -
My code for uploading the files and making the URL:

```
        else:
            new_folder_name = shortuuid.uuid()[:9] 
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(app.config['FILE_FOLDER'], new_folder_name))
            file.save(os.path.join(os.path.join(app.config['FILE_FOLDER'], new_folder_name), filename))
            new_folder_path = os.path.join(app.config['FILE_FOLDER'], new_folder_name)
            return url_for('uploaded_file', new_folder_name=new_folder_name)
```

My code for serving the files:

```
@app.route('/<new_folder_name>', methods=['GET'])
def uploaded_file(new_folder_name):
    filename = subfolder_fetch(new_folder_name)
    return render_template("download.html", filename=filename)
```

and finally my code for fetching the filename from the subdirectory (called in the serving function - didn't pass the filename to the url_for function because that would make it ugly and complicated):

```
def subfolder_fetch(new_folder_name): 
    stuff = os.listdir(os.path.join(app.config['FILE_FOLDER'], new_folder_name))
    for name in folder: 
        print (name)
        return name
```

I'm puzzled as to what is even going on and why my uploaded_file function isn't even being called. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What url are you entering in the browser? At a guess the problem is that the route [needs a trailing slash](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#variable-rules). Regardless you probably shouldn't be rolling your own file upload mechanism, especially given the security concerns.

Comment: It was the trailing slash, darn it I am stupid. What security concerns? I'm using my own implementation of werkzeug's secure_filename and I banned HTML docs and such from being uploading to prevent XSS. Thanks for the help!